# Passing type annotation as an argument in a class

Tags: python, annotations

I have a class, which looks like this,

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, model):
       self.model = model
   
   def func(self, x: ???):
      pass
```

I want to use the model (am using pydantic BaseModel) that I pass to `__init__` in `func`

```
def func(self, x: self.model):
  pass
```

is invalid

Comment: Consider using [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) and annotating `model` and `x` as generic variable.

Comment: it says `TypeError: Fields of type "<class 'typing.Generic'>" are not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the class be [Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
   def __init__(self, model: T) -> None:
       self.model = model
   
   def func(self, x: T):
       return

a = A(1)

reveal_type(a)  # Revealed type is "A[int]"
reveal_type(a.func)  # Revealed type is "def (x: int) -> Any"
```